# useEffect is missing dependencies... eslint auto fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have hundreds of warnings `useEffect has missing dependencies...` in my app. It looks like eslint can fix them. But is there a way to fix ALL of them at once automatically?

If I do `eslint --fix .` it does not update any file, but error is show:

```
(node:49911) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 
'/Users/user/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript/package.json' 
of 'dist/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript.js'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
```

---

---

[image]

Comment: I would highly recommend fixing them one by one. Some dependencies change on every render causing an infinite loop.

Comment: is this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook